# Function parameter variables not declared in scope

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a  Singular Value Decomposition `linalg` function, but when I try to compile I'm getting an error where the the parameter values are for some reason not within the scope of the `try` block:

```
bool rmatrixsvd(const real_2d_array &a, const ae_int_t m, const ae_int_t n, const ae_int_t uneeded, const ae_int_t vtneeded, const ae_int_t additionalmemory, real_1d_array &w, real_2d_array &u, real_2d_array &vt)
{

alglib_impl::ae_state _alglib_env_state;
alglib_impl::ae_state_init(&_alglib_env_state);
try
{
    ae_bool result = alglib_impl::rmatrixsvd(const_cast<alglib_impl::ae_matrix*>(a.c_ptr()), temp_m, n, uneeded, vtneeded, additionalmemory, const_cast<alglib_impl::ae_vector*>(w.c_ptr()), const_cast<alglib_impl::ae_matrix*>(u.c_ptr()), const_cast<alglib_impl::ae_matrix*>(vt.c_ptr()), &_alglib_env_state);
    alglib_impl::ae_state_clear(&_alglib_env_state);
    return *(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&result));
}
catch(alglib_impl::ae_error_type)
  {
    throw ap_error(_alglib_env_state.error_msg);
  }

}
```

I keep getting these errors when I compile:

```
linalg.cpp:1891: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘real_2d_array’ with no type
linalg.cpp:1891: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
linalg.cpp:1893: error: ‘m’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘n’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘uneeded’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘vtneeded’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘additionalmemory’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘w’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘u’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1899: error: ‘vt’ was not declared in this scope
linalg.cpp:1905: error: ‘ap_error’ was not declared in this scope
```

`real_2d_array` is a class defined in another header file.

Can someone explain why I'm getting these scope errors, and why real_2d_array is not working properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Your casts concern me.

Comment: I didn't write any of this code. This is one function in the linalg.cpp file that's publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error is telling you that the compiler can find no definition for `real_2d_array`. To make progress you'll need to work out why you think that `real_2d_array` should be defined, but the compiler cannot see anything of that name. Perhaps you failed to include the necessary file. Or perhaps `real_2d_array` is defined in a namespace.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why the variables (e.g., m, a, n, w, vt) aren't in the scope of the `try` block?

Comment: That looks like simply a consequence of the original program. The parser is confused by the original error.

Comment: Thank you; I'll see if I can iron out the class issue.